# Ajax form submission - typo3

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, typo3, extbase

I have an extbase TYPO3 extension. It contains a model `window` with a form. On submit an ajax call updates the underlying table via `updateAction`. My problem is how to get the form argument via `getArgument()`-method in the controller. My code is given below.

My form is:

```
<form id="updatewindow" method="POST"  name="iframe">
    <p><label for="fields">' + $(title).html() + ':</label>
    <input type="text" value="' + cell_data + '" name="tx_suserform_userform[newUser][name]"></p>
</form>
```

Ajax Call:

```
url_update = '<f:uri.action  action="updateFileds" absolute="1" noCacheHash="1"/>';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url_update,
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'true') {
            location.reload();
        } else {
        }
    }
});
```

In my controller I wrote

```
$post_val = $this->request->getArgument('name');
```

but it returns **error** and

```
$this->request->getArguments()
```

only returns the controller name and action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`$this->request->getArguments()`** receives the post/get arguments in the format

```
$pluggin_signature['argument']
```

so I passed the parameters in that format from ajax.Here is my code

```
url_update = '<f:uri.action  action="updateFileds" absolute="1" noCacheHash="1"/>';
var params = {'tx_pluggin_signature[name]':'test','tx_pluggin_signature[phone]':'(456) 456-2345'};
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url_update,
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'true') {
            location.reload();
        } else {
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly.. What I needed to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the form data using JavaScripts `FormData` object:

```
url_update = '<f:uri.action  action="updateFileds" absolute="1" noCacheHash="1"/>';
var params = new FormData(jQuery('#updatewindow').get(0));
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url_update,
    type: "POST",
    data: params,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'true') {
            location.reload();
        } else {
        }
    }
});
```

You should probably render your form using fluid, otherwise some stuff extbase relies on will be missing from the form (check the hidden div in any fluid generated form).

To get the URL to POST the data to, I'd recommend using the extension [`typoscript_rendering`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/typoscript_rendering) - it's made for this exact purpose. It generates an URL which won't return the whole HTML page, but only the result from the template of the called action. You need to have cHashes enabled to use it.

Comment: When using formData I got the following error :   TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.

Comment: Where do you get that error? In the call to `jQuery.ajax`, or in the `var params` line?

Comment: In    jquery.min.js (line 6)

Comment: When console(params) i got 
FormData { append=append()}  dont getting any form data

Comment: I updated the form o fluid.but the form is not displaying :(. Please  help me

Comment: I got an alternative solution for my problem

Comment: Could you post it as an answer, please?

Comment: I posted my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124255/discussion-between-aswathy-s-and-jost).